C# filter referenced assemblies on calling assembly
I have a classlib and a solution located in different directories.
from classlib I am calling GetCallingAssembly that returns an executable from solution followed by callingAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies that returns the references, now I want to perform an optimization to filter out the references and remove all package refs, aiming to find a certain type.
Note: I don't want to depend on Name property of references.


"now I want to perform an optimization to filter out the references and remove all package refs" - what do you mean by this?

What is AggregateRoot in this context?

Do not post images of code. Post code.

@Dai I mean filtering referencedAssemblies to take out package references.
currently, referencedAssemblies is a list of all assemblies referenced by the callingAssembly, including Microsoft and AspNetCore assemblies that I want to filter to optimize the foreach.

@Dai AggregateRoot is base class of my aggregate type that I want to find.

@Fildor I was thinking this could further help understanding my purpose, the idea is simple as I am looking to see if we can differentiate between package versus project references when calling GetReferencedAssemblies.

@SarwanSurchi PackageReferences are managed by your build system (MSBuild), Assembly-references are the only thing csc.exe cares about. PackageReferences usually end-up resulting in an Assembly-reference (but not always). They are not either-or options.

@Dai so there is no way to find out which assembly, among  the ones I received, in simple terms, I created and which is a third-party?

@SarwanSurchi I don't know what you're talking about - there's no such thing as a "third-party assembly" as far as the CLR is concerned....

@Dai how do look for a type in response of a method call from your assembly?
well to help both of us understand the context, first thing you do is get calling assembly followed by get referenced assemblies against calling and you end up having a bunch of assembles in which one of them contains my type, problem here is loading types of each assembly isn't performance-wise, a filter is needed to take out assemblies like Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Microsoft.AspNetCore, etc.
I hope that you understand my problem now :)

"well to help both of us understand the context, first thing you do is get calling assembly followed by get referenced assemblies against calling and you end up having a bunch of assembles in which one of them contains my type," - No, that's not the way to do it. I suggest instead that you enumerate types from all loaded assemblies in the current AppDomain - there's no need to traverse the graph of assembly references.

AppDomain isn't going to help as current assembly doesn't reference calling assembly.

@SarwanSurchi ...I think you misunderstand what the AppDomain is.

true my mistake, I though a reference is required to have the assembly in AppDomain.

...if you just want to find all types in all loaded assemblies that are derived from your AggregateRoot type, without searching assemblies that can't possibly contain a subclass, then all you need is this:
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypesDerivedFromAggregateRoot()
{
    Assembly[] asses = AppDomain.Current.GetAssemblies();

    Type typeofRoot = typeof(AggregateRoot);
    AssemblyName mustReferenceThisAssembly = typeofRoot.Assembly.GetName();

    List<Assembly> candidates = asses
        .Where( ass => ass
            .GetReferencedAssemblies()
            .Any( ra => AssemblyName.ReferenceMatches( reference: ra, definition: mustReferenceThisAssembly ) )
        )
        .ToList();

    foreach( Assembly candidate in candidates )
    {
        Type[] types = candidate.GetTypes();
        foreach( Type t in types )
        {
            if( typeofRoot.IsAssignableFrom( t ) ) yield return t;
        }
    }
}


You nailed it @Dai thank you. didn't know AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition() exists and is all I needed. however, don't you think (in my case) using the caller is better instead of AppDomain which leads to a fewer assemblies to deal with?
and here is my hack of the code in case you are interested.
var ideals = caller.GetReferencedAssemblies().Where(x =>  Assembly.Load(x).GetReferencedAssemblies() .Any(x => AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition(x, mustReferenceAssembly)));

@SarwanSurchi "don't you think (in my case) using the caller is better instead of AppDomain which leads to a fewer assemblies to deal with?" - No, I don't, because using your approach you aren't getting a complete view of your program.

well I have the caller assembly that triggered a method, first thing I do is to see if my type is in the caller assembly itself for optimization. if not, then I use the caller to get references that satisfy a condition, must reference aggregateroot assembly.
moreover, thanks a lot this was great.

@SarwanSurchi Another reason: your approach simply won't work if there's a proxy assembly or runtime generated code (e.g. like what we get with Entity Framework, Linq, etc) sitting in-between the actual caller and your assembly.

well let's hope this won't happen for me (not sure how common is this though), don't want to deal with complexities at this level and go deeper.

Afterall not sure if you are interested but if you are, the caller is an Api with a few classlibs, calling AddEventSourcing extension which triggers what we have discussed, and AddEventSourcing is located in a separate solution which is my event sourcing framework.
Now the reason that my extension isn't generic where I simply send my aggregate, is not force clients specify an aggregate. instead, this is what I do finding optional aggregates and resolve my generic repositories into IoC.

@SarwanSurchi Generic-Repositories are an anti-pattern. Don't use them.

Agree they are hard to deal with thanks for the lesson, but what practice encourages this? probably composition? @Dai

@SarwanSurchi Composition has nothing to do with it. It's about not wasting time adding abstractions that add no value and only create anti-work in the long-term.

well in my situation I need generics to accomplish my purpose, can't think of a better way for now.

@SarwanSurchi Seeming as you seem generally happy with my answer - even if only as inspiration, can you at least mark it as your accepted answer?

by all means, just accepted and thank you again.
